# Copy MSI into a directory as part of installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using the latest release of WiX to build my installer projects, and need a solution to my problem...

When I install **ProductA.msi**, i want **ProductA.msi** to copy itself into a directory, call it **%PROGRAMFILES%\ProductA\Installer**- so that the installer i used is available for re-use at **%PROGRAMFILES%\ProductA\Installer\ProductA.msi**

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You are aware that msiexec caches installers already, aren't you?

Comment: Windows Installer usually keeps a copy of all installers in %windir%\Installer. Refer to answer at http://superuser.com/questions/473569/where-does-windows-store-msi-files-for-uninstallation for locating your installer.

Comment: @sttaq - there shouldn't be a need to *locate* the installer - there's a reason why `msiexec` accepts package IDs as an alternative to a path to an `.msi`.

Comment: Unsure why this was voted down... thanks for the answer- i need to be able to access the installer so that remote connecting clients can get a copy of what is installed.

Comment: @TomBeech not sure why it was voted down. If the comment above answer your question then I can put it down as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you like to do is ok.

BUT:
You can write a .bat File with robocopy that copies the msi and its files to destination and starts the .msi afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing and ended up tossing in a powershell script as a custom action.  WiX has the [OriginalDatabase] property which points to the .msi being run.  I just passed that in as an argument to a quick script and it works.

```
param(
[string]$MsiLocation
)

echo "Creating directory"
md -Force "C:\directory"

echo "Removing current files"
rm "C:\directory\*"

echo "Copying in new .msi"
cp "$MsiLocation" "C:\directory\"
```

It's not elegant but it gets the job done.  You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091174/make-vdproj-msi-installer-copy-itself-locally-after-successful-install) for more details.